# How do I use nonstatic methods?

Tags: java, static, drawstring

I have been searching for a while, and the documentation nor Google return a good answer. I just started using java, so help me out here. I am getting an error with

```
Graphics.drawString('hello',10, 10);
```

However all the documentation is telling me is that I nedd to use str,int, int.
My error is:

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method drawString(str,int,int) from the type Graphics
```

So does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You should understand these basic concepts before understanding GUI applications. Tutorials are available on Oracle: [Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) and [Generic Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html)

Comment: I strongly suggest you read a good introductory Java textbook to become familiar with the basic concepts (i.e. the difference between static and non-static).

Comment: Please post a reduced sample of your entire class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to have an instance of `Graphics` to use, exactly as the error message says.

i.e.,

```
Graphics graphics = new Graphics();
graphics.drawString("hello", 10, 10);
```

Basically, `static` methods are invoked from the class, while non-static methods must be invoked using an actual object of that class.

You will need to get the `Graphics` instance from somewhere, though, as the [Graphics constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#Graphics()) is `protected` rather than `public`, and the class itself is `abstract`.  (For a beginner, all this means is that you need to already have the object somewhere to work with, since you can't create it directly for yourself.)

Also, side note: the single quote is used for `char` literals, while the double quote is used for `String` literals.

Comment: Groditz, be sure to select and answer and give out rep where its due.

Answer (score 2):

The **drawString()** method is not static.  This means you need an instance of the Graphics (or Graphics2D) object.   Normally when you use this object it is passed to you as the parameter to the **paint()** method.